# SQL: two nullable attributes and one of them should have value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how can I make two attributes in my table nullable and in the same time one of them should have a value.

For example:
I have attribute A and attribute B in table X,
A and B Allow Nulls BUT if A null B should not be null and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't really implement constraints.  So, you have two choices.  The first is to implement the logic using a trigger, which I don't recommend because of the complexity.

The second is to store have two columns: `AttributeType` and `AttributeValue`.  `AttributeType` would be either "A" or "B", and value would be the associated value.  If you want to ensure that `AttributeType` only takes on those two values, then you can use an `enum`.